# Select column referenced in variable

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm currently working on a MySQL ***trigger*** (this is important because this rules out `PREPARE/EXECUTE` combos) that gets a Pokémon's type and looks up its affinity with another given type. Here is the fragment of the trigger I'm working with:

```
select `type1`,`type2` into @t1,@t2
    from `data_pokemon` where `formeid`=new.`formeid`;
set @t3 = 'electric'; -- actually obtained from another select query
set @q = concat(
    'select `',@t1,'`',
    if(@t2 is null,'/2',concat('*`',@t2,'`/4')),
    ' into @aff from `data_types` where `attack`=?'
);
prepare tmp from @q;
execute tmp using @t3;
deallocate prepare tmp;
```

Now, as I mentioned, this is a trigger. Therefore, the above code won't work.

What I could really do with is a way to select a row, then treat it like some kind of associative array, so I could access `@typerow[@t1]`. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: As an aside: it appears as though you are trying to push a lot of business logic into your database layer... are you sure this is right architecture for your application?

Comment: More to the point, perhaps you can entirely avoid this problem by adopting the [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) to replace your many different "type" columns.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I've rewritten this part in PHP, and I'll just have to make sure to update appropriately when the trigger would have been called.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can come is a giant case statement:

```
select (case when @t1 = 'col1' then col1
             when @t1 = 'col2' then col2
        . . .
        end
       ) . . .
```

One caveat is that this will convert all the columns to the same type.